# How do you transition tab bar controller programmatically, i need to switch the selected index with code and not by swiping

Tags: cosmicmind

AppPageTabBarController(viewControllers: [Controller1, Controller2, Controller3], selectedIndex: 0)

Comment: I had thought this feature was accessible from `PageTabBarController`. It is not, so I am going to put this as a feature request. Thank you :)

Comment: Here is the link, [associated GitHub feature request](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/652).